# Android 5.0 - Intellij Gradle: Cannot resolve symbol: @color:material_blue_500

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I am trying to customize the material design theme as suggested in this link :
[android dev](http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html)

but when I add the following code to my v21/styles file Intellij says that it cannot resolve these symbols.

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- customize the color palette -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/material_blue_700</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/material_green_A200</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I looked around to see if there are any particular settings that need to be done on the color side but nothing came up. I am using API 21 with support lib v7 on gradle.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`@color/material_blue_500` and others are not the resources in android library.

You must define the color resources in `res/values/colors.xml` by yourself.

such as `<color name="material_blue_500">#5677fc</color>`.

And then you can use it as `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/material_blue_500</item>`.

Comment: sorry i should have done more research.. colors for material views are given here: http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#

Answer (score 7):

Android docs are very vague on this, leading to confusion. To get the predefined colors copy [color_material.xml](https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/b5e564cfe11619cc3999) to your local res/values dir. That file is a preserved version as it was during Android-L. The offical version which sits in your local directory:

...sdk/platforms/android-21/data/res/values/colors_material.xml

has been trimmed down to remove those color definitions.